# Regex pegar de um ponto ate o outro dentro de um texto

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Tenho o seguinte texto:

```
From: .... blabla bla
Message: blablabalab

//linha em branco

From: .... blabla bla
Message: blablabalab

//linha em Branco

From: .... blabla bla
Message: blablabalab
```

Como faço minha regex pegar onde começa o `From` e para antes de começar o próximo `From`?

Até agora tenho a seguinte regex: `From\s\-\s\w{3}\s\w{3}([^\n]*\n+)+`. O que eu quero é que cada parte do texto que contenha `From` até começar outro `From` fique em um grupo. Só que a minha regex tah pegando tudo até o final do texto.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: E precisa ser `RegEx`?

Comment: Qual seria outra forma? @bigown

Comment: Eu só não respondi com outra forma porque você diz querer `RegEx` e porque não entendi completamente o padrão. Talvez poderia usar um simples `Split`. Talvez ele não resolva e precisaria fazer um laço descobrindo o ponto de quebra com `IndexOf` e pegar o que interessa com `Substring`. Eu acho mais intuito, embora entenda que outras pessoas se virem melhor com `RegEx`. Claro que sem um padrão claro, qualquer solução é difícil.

Comment: Bom, após seu questionamento se precisa usar regex, me lembrei do `Regex.Split`. Então modifiquei a regex para pegar somente a parte do `From`. Uso regex porque no `From` contém datas e elas sempre mudam. Assim tenho exatamente o que queria. Obrigado.

Comment: Legal ter resolvido, mas eu acho que o `string.Split()` já resolveria. Coloque a resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o `Regex.Split()`, com a regex `@"From\s\-\s\w{3}\s\w{3}[^\n]*\n+"`.

1 - Estou usando regex pois quero pegar a partir do primeiro `From - Fri Mar 13 10:58:58 2015`
Até o começo do próximo. E neste intevalo há outros `From` no meio da mensagem, só que sem a data.

então ficou assim:

`string[] split = Regex.Split(texto, rgxSplit);`

Ele me retornara um array com todos os textos que estão entre um `From - ...` e outro.

Answer (score 6):

Montei uma outra expressão regular pra você que ficou assim:

```
From:\s*([\.\w\d\s]*)\nMessage:\s*([\.\w\d\s]*)\n
```

[Fiz uma prova de conceito aqui](http://regexr.com/3ak4i).

Answer (score 4):

Tem o método [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) que pode ser utilizado para isso.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
....

public static void Main() {
        string texto = @"From: .... blabla bla
        Message: blablabalab

        //linha em branco
        From: .... blabla bla
        Message: blablabalab

        //linha em Branco
        From: .... blabla bla
        Message: blablabalab";

        string[] pedacos = Regex.Split(texto, "From:\\s+");
        foreach (var pedaco in pedacos){
            Console.WriteLine(pedaco);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Porém nesse caso não é necessário usar esse método porque não envolve expressões regulares, então o [`Split`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) *tradicional* pode ser melhor usado aqui.

Se for necessário ter múltiplos delimitadores, o seguinte pode ser feito:

```
string[] pedacos = texto.Split(new string[] { "From: ", "Message: " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var pedaco in pedacos){
    Console.WriteLine(pedaco);
}
```

Exemplo funcional [aqui](https://ideone.com/5RrzV2).

Comment: No meu caso tenho dois `From`, um assim `From - Fri Mar 13 10:58:58 2015` e antes de começar o outro no mesmo padrão, tenho um `From:`. Então por isso estou a usar `Regex.Split()`

Answer (score 3):

Boa gente, decidi que era uma vergonha nunca ter feito um programa em c#. Vai daí (o momento é solene!) instalei o mono e tentei ver se a ideia Perl era aplicável. É. Fiquei tão contente que resolvi escrever nova resposta!

Sendo estas as minhas primeiras 10 linhas de c#, sugestóes construtivas são bemvindas.

Para diferenciar, enriqueci a expressão regular de modo a separar componentes (from/mensagem):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program{
    static void Main(){
       string text = @"From:.....(Cut&paste exemplo da pergunta)....balab\n";

       Regex r = new Regex(@"(From:(.*)\n((.|\n)+?\n)(?=From:|$))");
       MatchCollection m= r.Matches(text);
       foreach (Match k in m) {
 //       Console.WriteLine("##Full# " + k.Groups[1].Value);
          Console.WriteLine("##From# " + k.Groups[2].Value);
          Console.WriteLine("##Mesg# " + k.Groups[3].Value);
       }
    }
 }
```

após `$ gmcs regexp.cs ; regexp.exe` a saída foi:

```
##From#  .... blabla bla
##Mesg# Message: blablabalab

//linha em branco

##From#  .... blabla bla
##Mesg# Message: blablabalab

//linha em Branco

##From#  .... blabla bla
##Mesg# Message: blablabalab
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ok, não é bem c# nem .net mas aqui vai uma expressão regular

`/(.+?\n)(?=From:|$)/s`

que penso estar dentro do espírito do enunciado. Exemplo de uso:

```
perl -n0E 'for $mail ( m/(.+?\n)(?=From:|$)/sg ){ 
                  print "===\n", $mail
           }' file
```

com o exemplo da pergunta dá

```
===
From: .... blabla bla
Message: blablabalab

//linha em branco

===
From: .... blabla bla
Message: blablabalab

//linha em Branco

===
From: .... blabla bla
Message: blablabalab
```